# Is it possible to missmatch opening and end tags in xml on purpose?

Tags: django, xml, parsing, text, edit

So, a few literary students tried to digitaly edit some text and unfortunatly they've ended up with a few hundred pages of

```
<author> H.P.Lovecraft <authorEnd>
<placeTime> Arkham <placeTimeEnd>
```

I'm now writing a django application to shape those into something somewhat  usefull.

I do have a working function to check and replace them, but it's really clumsy and awkward. 
Now I'm wondering, if you could replace     < /author> somehow with < /authorEnd> and use an xml-parse to process the whole thing. 
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for redirecting me to the answer. Have a nice day!